# Can we have a different Icon and Name in Task module

Tags: botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

I am building chatbot using Bot framewokV4 on MS teams.
Can we use different Icon and Name for the task module?
By default, it is showing bot name and Image.
Is there a way to change the Icon and name for Task module than Bot name and Image.

Thanks.

Comment: Task Module picks up the icon and name of the app. It is not possible to change the icon or the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Task Module will use the name and icon from your Team's app definition (your manifest, or your definition from App Studio if you're using that to create/deploy), not from the Azure bot settings.

In that case, you can change the Task Module's name and image by changing the App's icon and name. You'll need to redeploy it though of course to see the changes.